# List the files in the directory using GWT

Tags: file, gwt, file-io, filesystems

I tried the following code,

```
File folder = new File("/path/of/the/directory");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        if ((listOfFiles[i].getName()).contains(".xml")) {
            Window.alert("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        }
    }
}
```

But, I got this error:

```
No source code is available for type java.io.File; did you forget to inherit a required module ?
```

Can anyone help me to do the same using GWT?

Thanks in advance,
Gnik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**

You cannot use the `Java.io.File` class in GWT.

Except if you use [gwt-filesystem](https://github.com/bradrydzewski/gwt-filesystem)

**"Large" answer**

From [groups](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/3df60fc7a0368246) :

> You won't be able to use java.io.File on the client.
>   You can't access the client's file system without using an Applet,
>   Flash, ActiveX, or other component to which the user has granted
>   permission.

You should go to the Google Documentation about the [JRE Emulation Reference](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html#Package_java_io).

According to the documentation :

> Google Web Toolkit includes a library that emulates a subset of the Java runtime library. The list below shows the set of JRE packages, types and methods that GWT can translate automatically. Note that in some cases, only a subset of methods is supported for a given type.

---

However, you can use the [gwt-filesystem](https://github.com/bradrydzewski/gwt-filesystem) project :

> This library adds browser-based FileSystem support to applications developed using Google Web Toolkit (GWT), based on the HTML5 FileSystem specification.

Comment: Sandro Munda, Thanks. But i'm not able to get the dependecy of gwt-filesystem (i.e jar file). Can you give me the website where i can download the jar file?    Thanks in advance, Gnik

Comment: 1) Take the zip : https://github.com/bradrydzewski/gwt-filesystem/zipball/master 2) unzip and do a mvn package in order to have the .jar.

Comment: Sandro,  Thanks. I got the jar file. Thank you very much. Gnik

Comment: Sandro,

I tried to list the files in my local directory. But was not able to do it. Can you give me sample code to get the list of files in a directory using gwt-filesystem.

Thanks in advance, Gnik

Comment: Sandro, Can you give me sample code to get the list of files in a directory using gwt-filesystem. Thanks in advance,
Gnik

Comment: Also give me sample code to read a file using gwt-filesystem. I waiting for your reply. Thanks, Gnik

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Works fine with GWT 2.6.1 and appengine sdk 1.9.13 deployed to App Engine
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    java.io.File folder = new File(".");
    java.io.File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
       sb.append(listOfFiles[i].getName() +"\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
```

listOfFiles[i].isFile()) would throw a java.security.AccessControlException but the above worked.  It returned the file and folder names top level in my war by default, e.g., _ah WEB-INF home.html favicon.ico testfile.txt home.css home